# Perl my find on a certain column

Tags: perl

I am trying to get my `elsif` to work with regard to copying the lines after my header is captured. Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = "^(M0|MT|H0|HT|J0|JT)";
my $header;

open (NEW, ">", "output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";

open (FILE, "<", "input.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {

    if ( /^\s*TRANSACTION/ ) {
        ($header) = /(TRANSACTION\w+)/;
    }
    elsif ( /^\h{4}/$find/ ) {
        print NEW "$header\t", $_;
    }
}
close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

Input file example

```
                     REMOTE: 00000  TYPE: GENERAL    PAYER NAME: PAYER
                        ISA(1000000)   GS(100000000)   ST(10000000)
                            TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)

PATIENT         CLAIM        BILL  STATEMENT   STATEMENT                                  FILE   
ACCOUNT #       AMOUNT       TYPE  FROM DATE   THRU DATE   NUMBER              DATE    CREATE DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```

Expected output file

```
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)     MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)     MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)     MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $find = qr/(?:M0|MT|H0|HT|J0|JT)/;
my $header;

# open (my $NEW, ">", "output.txt" );
# open (my $FILE, "<", "input.txt");
my $FILE = \*DATA;
my $NEW = \*STDOUT;

while (<$FILE>) {
    if ( /^\s*(TRANSACTION[^\r\n]+)/ ) {
        $header = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^\h{0,4}$find/) {
        print $NEW "$header\t", $_;
    }
}
close ($FILE);
close ($NEW);

__DATA__
                     REMOTE: 00000  TYPE: GENERAL    PAYER NAME: PAYER
                        ISA(1000000)   GS(100000000)   ST(10000000)
                            TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)

PATIENT         CLAIM        BILL  STATEMENT   STATEMENT                                  FILE   
ACCOUNT #       AMOUNT       TYPE  FROM DATE   THRU DATE   NUMBER              DATE    CREATE DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```

output

```
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```

Comment: Thank you, I see where my mistake was now.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several issues - your `/(TRANSACTION\w+)/` pattern will never match - `elsif (/^\h{4}/$find/) {` is a syntax error so your code doesn't run at all.

Finally you don't need an `elsif` at all - you can just set the header then do a separate test for your record matching e.g.

```
while (<FILE>) {
    $header = $1 if /^\s*(TRANSACTION .+)(?=\s+|$)/;
    if (/$find/) {
        print NEW "$header\t", $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `elsif` is appropriate here because a line that matches the `TRANSACTION` pattern will never match the `$find` pattern. Removing the `elsif` makes the code do two tests on every line instead of just one

Answer (score 0):

I would write this. It's not very different from your own code or either of the solutions, but it's a little more concise and I think it is clearer

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $find = qr/[MHJ][0T]/;

my $header;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    if ( /^\s*(TRANSACTION.*\S)/ ) {
        $header = $1;
    }
    elsif ( $header and /^\s*$find/ ) {
        print "$header\t$_";
    }
}

__DATA__
                     REMOTE: 00000  TYPE: GENERAL    PAYER NAME: PAYER
                        ISA(1000000)   GS(100000000)   ST(10000000)
                            TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)

PATIENT         CLAIM        BILL  STATEMENT   STATEMENT                                  FILE   
ACCOUNT #       AMOUNT       TYPE  FROM DATE   THRU DATE   NUMBER              DATE    CREATE DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```

#### output

```
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $14,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $11,000.00   111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16  
TRANSACTION SET STATUS - A (Accepted)   MT000000000     $5,000.00    111   01/01/16    02/01/16    XXXXXXXXX         01/01/01    03/21/16
```